# Gradle finished with non-zero exit value 2?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google Sign-in into my app 
[Google developer](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).
As mentioned I have also added to build.gradle files as follows:

dependency to project's top-level build.gradle:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'`

plugin to app-level build.gradle:

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

when I start syncing,it downloads some stuff.

But after running it shows error that Gradle finished with non-zero exit value 2.

Currently I am using `Android Studio v1.4`

Comment: post your error stacktrace please...

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of this would be, you have a lot of libraries and thus lots of methods. Try enable `multiDex` in your app's `build.gradle` like below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.alphawolf.wallmax"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true                          // Like this
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

and you will be able to build your project!